# asp.net core application not running in IIS

Tags: asp.net-core, iis

I am currently trying to run an .net core application on IIS, but for some reason am I not hitting the application?

The code consist of this program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddReverseProxy().LoadFromConfig(builder.Configuration.GetSection("ReverseProxy"));

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseSwagger(x => x.SerializeAsV2 = true);
app.UseSwaggerUI();
app.MapReverseProxy();

//app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

when deployed to IIS and trying to access one the address listed in the bindings
I get 404, but when accessing /swagger/index.html I get 200 with no content?

Why does it give me 404?

I am having a hard time determining whether my setup works, or something is wrong?

how do I determine that?

Logs from IIS

```
2022-04-21 09:54:53 ::1 GET / - 5147 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko - 404 0 0 7
2022-04-21 09:54:57 ::1 GET / - 2500 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko - 404 0 0 0
2022-04-21 09:55:42 ::1 GET / - 5147 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko - 404 0 0 5
2022-04-21 09:55:46 ::1 GET /swagger/ - 5147 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko - 301 0 0 9
2022-04-21 09:55:46 ::1 GET /swagger/index.html - 5147 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko - 200 0 0 115
2022-04-21 09:55:46 ::1 GET /swagger/swagger-ui.css - 5147 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko http://localhost:5147/swagger/index.html 200 0 0 47
2022-04-21 09:55:46 ::1 GET /swagger/swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js - 5147 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko http://localhost:5147/swagger/index.html 200 0 0 57
2022-04-21 09:55:46 ::1 GET /swagger/swagger-ui-bundle.js - 5147 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko http://localhost:5147/swagger/index.html 200 0 0 122
2022-04-21 09:55:46 ::1 GET /swagger/favicon-32x32.png - 5147 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64;+Trident/7.0;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko - 200 0 0 0
2022-04-21 09:55:56 127.0.0.1 GET / - 7147 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko - 404 0 0 0
```

Comment: It's not certain what kind of web app you created. Many of them (for example, a Web API web app) just returns 404 on `/`, and nothing is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `options.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;` to fix this issue.

**Like below：**

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
{
    options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "v1");
    options.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
});
```

**Official doc:**

[Get started with Swashbuckle and ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#add-and-configure-swagger-middleware)